# How to Install Truffle Framework on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: truffle

I cant install Truffle Framework the terminal show a lot of error

```
Auppakarasakun@Macintosh ~ % npm install -g truffle@5.0.2
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Auppakarasakun/.npm/_logs/2021-05-29T05_16_56_551Z-debug.log
Auppakarasakun@Macintosh ~ % node -v
v14.17.0
```

My nodejs version is 14.17.0 and also I try to put sudo in front npm and I have to enter password but it can't type anything

```
Auppakarasakun@Macintosh ~ % sudo npm install --g truffle@5.0.2
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```